# Can't figure out why I can't import this one class, I feel like it should work

Tags: python, class, import

I made a simple class in a file that is in the same directory to where I'm trying to send it. However, for some unknown reason I can't for the life of me figure out why the import won't work. Any help would be great.

I've googled around a lot already but can't find anything specific to me

the class in question (file named location1.py)

```
class Location:
    def __init__(self, name, txt_display, been_there):
        self.name = name
        self.txt_display = txt_display
        self.been_there = been_there
```

all my imports (file named mainPart1.py)

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from location1 import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

how I'm testing it

```
temp = Loction("1a", "display poo", True)
print(temp.name)
```

"NameError: name 'Loction' is not defined"
I get this from the terminal and I don't know what to do.
I expected "1a"

Comment: Read the error message: you misspelled the class name.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo there, it should be `Location`

Your code:

```
temp = Loction("1a", "display poo", True)
```

Should be:
`temp = Location("1a", "display poo", True`)